# "rails" is not internal or external team

Tags: redmine, bitnami

**I use**
Windows 7x64
bitnami
redmine-3.4.3-2
Installed in the directory: `E:\srw\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.3-2`

I work with the book "Redmine Plugin Extension and Development"

*a QUOTE from the book:*

> "Running rails genera te from the root of our Redmine installation will provide a list of available generators (truncated in the following snippet to list only those that are currently relevant):

```
$ rails generate
RedminePlugin:
        redmine_plugin
RedminePluginController:
      redmine_plugin_controller
RedminePluginModel:
      redmine plugin model
```

I launch

```
E:\srw\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.3-2\use_redmine.bat
```

I try to execute the command `$ rails generate`
I receive the message

> e:\srw\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.3-2\apps\redmine> rails generate
>   "rails" is not internal or external
>   command, executable program or batch file.

Question.
How to make the team work?

Comment: is `rails` in the directory `e:\srw\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.3-2\apps\redmine`

Comment: If you do not understand English, you need to find someone that can understand English and assist in translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running the commands shown on this page, you should load the Bitnami stack environment by clicking the shortcut in the Start Menu under "Start -> Bitnami APPNAME Stack -> Application console" (Windows). [Learn more](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/components/bnconsole).

Also, take into account you should use `bundle exec` before your rails commands:

```
$ bundle exec rails --version
Rails 4.2.8
```

Comment: The command was launched.
The console offered recommendations.
See the link https://codeshare.io/5gCongB.

Do I have to make these recommendations?